# Android Camera Capture Resolution

Tags: java, android, camera, android-videoview

I use the front camera to capture user action when he uses the apps. And I will save the video to the device. I will use the `VideoView` to play the video. I saw the camera preview's `(FrameLayout)` resolution is correct(480 x 640). But I play on the `VideoView` the resolution change to (176 x 144). Now I saw the video view is too small. I already set the `setPictureSize`. But also not work.

When I used the `Camera` apps in the device, I used the front camera to capture something. Its resolution is 480 x 640. Do I set something is wrong? Please help. Thanks

```
for (int i = 0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
Camera.CameraInfo newInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
Camera.getCameraInfo(i, newInfo);

if (newInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
    mCamera = Camera.open(i); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    if (cameraDelegate != null)
        cameraDelegate.OnCameramCreated();
    }
}
```

```
private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){
    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
    mCamera.unlock();
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    // Step 2: Set sources
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);

    // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
//       mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

    mVideoPath = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString();

    // Step 4: Set output file
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mVideoPath);

    // Step 5: Set the preview output
//        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

    // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Camera`'s preview size is not the same thing to the `MediaRecorder`'s video size. You must specify the video size to the `MediaRecorder`.

```
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(960, 640);
```

But be careful that not all size is supported, and the supported sizes are determined by the camera hardware, see [Camera.Parameters#getSupportedVideoSizes()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedVideoSizes()).

The `MediaRecord.setProfile()` is a better way to config video output format, there are some predefined [CamcorderProfiles](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile) which contains settings about `output format`, `frame rate`, `video size`, `encoding bitrate`, etc. You should give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just try to setVideoSize. But I got the crash. `java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.` And I cannot get the `getSupportedVideoSizes()`. It return null.

Comment: If `getSupportedVideoSizes()` returns null, then use sizes from `getSupportedPreviewSizes()` instead. I suppose your size is not in the list, confirm the width and height is used in the right order.

Comment: I also use the `getSupportedPreviewSize` to set  the videoSize?

Comment: Yes, the doc says: `getSupportedVideoSizes()` returns 'a list of Size object if camera has separate preview and video output; otherwise, null is returned.' which means that if `Camera.getSupportedVideoSizes()` returns null, then the camera's supported preview sizes and video sizes are the same.

Comment: I would like to ask another question about the Camera. I just set the size  width is 640 height is 480. The video size has changed. But I don't know why  when I show the video on `VideoView`, I see the video rotation is not correct. I prefer the video view is `Portrait`. But I saw the view is `landscape`

Comment: See the sample code from android reference, [Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int)), simply set `mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);` may not work as expected, the surface's rotation and camera's orientation should both be considered.

Comment: I already set `mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90)` when I created the `mCamera`

Comment: 90 is not correct, see the code, there is a little computation based on the   surface's rotation and camera's orientation.

Comment: the surface's rotation contains info about the device's `portrait` or `landscape`.

Comment: I found the solution. set the `mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(270);`